# Why is this map function so complicated?

Tags: perl

When I run the below script I get

```
$VAR1 = 'ssh -o Compression=yes -o ConnectTimeout=333 remoteIp \'mbuffer -q -s 128k -m mbufferSize -4 -I mbufferPort|zfs recv recvOpt dstDataSet\'';
```

which leads me to think, that all `$shellQuote` does is converting an array to a string and adding a `'` in the beginning and end. Plus adding a `|` between two arrays. But the purpose of the `map` function can't I figure out.

The script is a super simplified version of [this](https://github.com/oetiker/znapzend/blob/master/lib/ZnapZend/ZFS.pm) in order to figure out what exactly `$shellQuote` does.

**Question**

`$shellQuote` looks very complicated. Does it do anything else I am missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $shellQuote = sub {
    my @return;

    for my $group (@_){
        my @args = @$group;
        for (@args){
            s/'/'"'"'/g;
        }
        push @return, join ' ', map {/^[-\/@=_0-9a-z]+$/i ? $_ : qq{'$_'}} @args;
    }

    return join '|', @return;
};

sub buildRemoteRefArray {
    my $remote = shift;

    my @sshCmdArray = (qw(ssh -o Compression=yes -o), 'ConnectTimeout=' . '333');

    if ($remote){
        return [@sshCmdArray, $remote, $shellQuote->(@_)];
    }

    return @_;
};


my @recvCmd = buildRemoteRefArray('remoteIp', ['mbuffer', (qw(-q -s 128k -m)), 'mbufferSize', '-4', '-I', 'mbufferPort'], ['zfs', 'recv', 'recvOpt', 'dstDataSet']);
my $cmd = $shellQuote->(@recvCmd);
print Dumper $cmd;
```

Comment: It's not that complicated, but it does do more than you seem to think -- it escapes all `'` in the arguments (to force them to be treated literally), and the map itself encloses all non-wordy arguments in single quotes (to force them to be treated literally).

Comment: Yes you are missing something. Compare output of `[ 'echo', 'test' ], [ 'log' ]` and `[ 'echo', q{He's got $100} ], [ 'log' ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore your code for a second and look at this one as it's a bit clearer.

```
# shell_quote_arg("foo bar") => 'foo bar'
sub shell_quote_arg {
   my ($s) = @_;
   return $s if $s !~ /[^-\/@=_0-9a-z]/i;
   $s =~ s/'/'"'"'/g;       # '
   return qq{'$s'}
}

# shell_quote("echo", "foo bar") => echo 'foo bar'
sub shell_quote {
    return join ' ', map { shell_quote_arg($_) } @_;
}

my $remote_shell_cmd1 = shell_quote('mbuffer', 'arg1a', 'arg1b');
my $remote_shell_cmd2 = shell_quote('zfs', 'arg2a', 'arg2b');
my $remote_shell_cmd = join(' | ', $remote_shell_cmd1, $remote_shell_cmd2);

my $local_shell_cmd = shell_quote('ssh', $host, $remote_shell_cmd);
```

My `shell_quote` is used to build a shell command from a program name and argument. For example,

```
shell_quote('zfs', 'recv', 'recvOpt', 'dstDataSet')
```

returns

```
zfs recv recvOpt dstDataSet
```

So why not just use `join(' ', 'zfs', 'recv', 'recvOpt', 'dstDataSet')`? Because characters such as spaces, `$` and `'` have special meaning to the shell. `shell_quote` needs to do extra work if these are present. For example,

```
shell_quote('echo', q{He's got $100})
```

returns

```
echo 'He'"'"'s got $100'       # When run, uses echo to output: He's got $100
```

The `shellQuote` you showed does the same thing as my `shell_quote`, but it also does the `join('|', ...)` you see in my code.

---

By the way, notice that `shellQuote` is called twice. The first time, it's used to build the command to execute on the remote machine, as the following does:

```
my $remote_shell_cmd1 = shell_quote('mbuffer', 'arg1a', 'arg1b');
my $remote_shell_cmd2 = shell_quote('zfs', 'arg2a', 'arg2b');
my $remote_shell_cmd = join(' | ', $remote_shell_cmd1, $remote_shell_cmd2);
```

The second time, it's used to build the command to execute on the local machine, as the following does:

```
my $local_shell_cmd = shell_quote('ssh', $host, $remote_shell_cmd);
```

Comment: I like your version much more. When I run your examples of `shell_quote` then it only prints the first argument and skips the rest. E.g. `shell_quote('echo', q{He's got $100})` outputs `echo`.

Comment: The new version now gives `'echo \'He\'s got $100\'` instead of `echo 'He'"'"'s got $100'`.

Comment: it really does. Try this http://pastebin.com/PErXTxX7 which produces `\'echo\' He\'s got $100`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65776/discussion-between-jasmine-lognnes-and-ikegami).

Answer (score 3):

The `map` function, by which I assume you mean

```
map {/^[-\/@=_0-9a-z]+$/i ? $_ : qq{'$_'}} @args
```

checks each argument to see if it is a legal shell token or not.  Legal shell tokens are passed through; anything with a suspicious character gets enclosed on '' quotes.

Bear in mind that your example has two calls to `$shellQuote`, not just one; you're printing:

```
print Dumper($shellQuote->(
    [
        qw(ssh -o Compression=yes -o),
            'ConnectTimeout=' . '333',
            'remoteIp',
            $shellQuote->(
                [
                    'mbuffer',
                        (qw(-q -s 128k -m)),
                        'mbufferSize',
                        '-4',
                        '-I',
                        'mbufferPort',
                ],
                [
                    'zfs',
                        'recv',
                        'recvOpt',
                        'dstDataSet',
                ],
            ),
    ]
));
```

Where I've indented the arguments to each shell command one step further than the command for clarity of the structure of the list.  So your '' quotes are coming from the outer `$shellQuote`, which is recognizing that the inner `$shellQuote` has put spaces into its result; the `|` is comming from the inner `$shellQuote`, which is using them to combine the the two array refs passed to it.

Breaking the `map` function down, `map { expr } @args` means 'evaluation `expr` for each element of `@args` and make a list of the results.

`/^[-\/@=_0-9a-z]+$/i ? $_ : qq{'$_'}` is a ternary expression (Googleable term).  `$_` is the current element of `@args`, and `/re/i` is true if and only if `$_` matches the given regular expression (Googleable term) (case insensitive).  The whole expression means 'if the current element of `@args` contains only the listed characters (ASCII letters, ASCII digits, and the characters `-`, `/`, `@`, and `=`), return it as-is; otherwise return it wrapped in single quotes'.

The `for` loop, before that, replaces each ' in each element of `@args` with `'"'"'`, which is a particular way of embedding a single quote into a single-quoted string in sh.